# Are these PCB , and if so can it be repaired?

Tags: soldering

I'm very new to soldering, and I think I have irreversibly damaged the circuit I was trying to fix.

[image]

The joints are pretty burnt, but I read that in some cases you can scrape the carbon off and get a workable joint. I'd very much like to know if I can save my circuit by doing so to these joints.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you use - a torch?

Comment: Photo quality isn't very good, but it looks like there's no pad left. If that's the case, bin it.

Comment: Next time, pre-heat the entire board before desoldering.

Comment: You can get repair eyelets and tracks from circuitmedic.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the copper pads have been ripped off.  It may be possible to salvage, but you're going to have to be really careful to prevent any further damage.  This looks like it might be a USB connector footprint.  Fortunately, it also looks like most of the traces connect to the pads on the bottom layer. If this wasn't the case, it may not be possible to fix.  What I would do is install the new connector and glue it to the board.  Solder a nice thick wire between the two large pads for mechanical support.   Then scrape the solder mask off of the two thin data traces, the thicker power trace, and the ground plane around the last pin. Use some 30 gauge wire wrap wire to connect the data pins to the traces and use a short piece of thicker wire to connect the power pin.

Also, you really should invest in the proper tools for rework if you haven't already.  Don't use a $5 soldering iron - you need a real temperature-controlled iron with a fine point.  You won't be able to rescue this board without decent tools.

Comment: Ok, let me make sure I understand this;

I should glue the USB connector to the board for stability, solder a  wire between the two large pins on the far left and right, wrap the wire and connect it to the four small pins after I scrape off the mask to the trace.

What I'm confused about is that I don't see any other traces besides the two, and I don't know what you mean by the "ground plane around the last pin"

I'm terribly new to this, so bear with me.

Comment: There is a thick trace that connects diagonally to the lower-right-hand pin.  This is probably the 5V power.  The ground plane is all of the lighter green, and it looks like it should be connected to the upper-right-hand pin.

Comment: @Ozymandias If you want to save this board I would strongly reccommend trying to find someone locally who knows what they are doing. You have already made quite a mess of things and while I don't think it's beyond repair yet it would be easy to make things worse rate than better. This stuff is more an art than a science and pretty hard to teach through online posts alone.

Comment: @PeterGreen, I'll look into the option, but I don't have much money for this type of thing at the moment, so I'd rather try my own hand at it if I get charged an arm and a leg.

Answer (score 0):

Yep easy.
Toothbrush and isopropyl alcohol or vodka.
voila.

Comment: That works if it's just a case of having made things a bit dirty with some flux residue but if he has actually ripped pads off (and I think he has) then he has a much harder repair job.

Comment: I know that IPA works OK for repairs and mods .Production people dont like the residue that the IPA leaves.I dont know about the spirits .Remember that 40% alc means 60% water.

Comment: @peter green yep very good point. I was focusing on the detritus  and didn’t notice the pad damage :)

Comment: @Autistic residue?  honestly don't think either leave anything  behind if they are used correctly. I clean glass with them :)

Comment: Rubbing alcohol is usually doctored with other substances to render it impotable, but IPA should boil off completely.